# What files do not get backed up when using Time Machine?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I am upgrading from a 2018 MBP to a new AirBook. The last time I did a factory reset, I didn't use Time Machine, and forgot to back up files like `~/.bach_profile`, `~/.zshrc`, and my `conda` environments. Will Time Machine back those up, or should I manually save them? Are there similar files that I'm not remembering?

On the flip side, my external monitor (a Dell 2719HC) has been causing Kernel Panics. Will this still happen when I restore my system from a Time Machine backup?

Comment: Generally speaking Time Machine backs up *user files* and user installed (non-Apple) apps, essentially, "Back up **your** files with Time Machine on Mac" https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/back-up-files-mh35860/mac . Emphasis added. That is a brief overview of what Time Machine does.

Comment: Pointing out that you should be making regular backups anyway, not just when you attempt a migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer here [How to export Time Machine exclusions or list them in Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440602/how-to-export-time-machine-exclusions-or-list-them-in-terminal) for how to discover what is excluded.

For your particular questions:

1. By default, your "dot" files and folders will be backed up.  But check by using Finder to look on your backup disk.
2. This really depends on why you are getting kernel panics. With a change from Intel to Apple silicon MacBook, that might avoid software related panics.  But if software issue it may follow you when you use Migration Assistant (from either your Time Machine backup or from the MBP).  I would advise a clean install of macOS, then install your apps and transfer files.