Time Machine is not backing up ~/Library/Application Support
Oddly, Time Machine quit backing up ~/Library/Application Support a month back. Nothing seems odd permission-wise, it was certainly backed up in the past. There are no exclusions for my ~.
How should I approach this?

This answer may help https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440602/how-to-export-time-machine-exclusions-or-list-them-in-terminal/440605#440605 To view .exclusions.plist you will need a plist aware editor like BBEdit. I am assuming recent macOS and APFS TM disk - if not please say.

Thanks!  tmutil isexcluded showed that ~/Library/Application Support was indeed excluded. tmutil removeexclusion removed it, no idea how it was excluded in the first place ...

Glad that helped!
